# WebApi Routing not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have one issue with WebApi routing. Please find the code snippet below-

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "reportsApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/list/",
               defaults: new { reports = RouteParameter.Optional  }
           );
```

Earlier it was working just fine and there is no change in the code of report module and it stopped working after the deployment of another version. 
My URL is something like that-

https://whatever.com/api/reports/list

When i remove '/list'  from the above url it works as expected.

Comment: One thing I notice is your defaults has an optional parameter (`reports`) that does not exist in your **routeTemplate**. If you need that, makes sure you have `{reports}` somewhere in your **routeTemplate**.

Comment: Thanks Paul, No i don't need that, as report doesn't take any parameter. For more understanding this is the output - No action was found on the controller 'Reports' that matches the name 'list'."

Comment: Paul, Entire message is 
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:54905/api/reports/list/'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Reports' that matches the name 'list'."}

Comment: Can you try - `https://whatever.com/api/reports/list/` with the trailing `/`.

Comment: ramiramilu, i did that. what i have noticed is i have added 

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "AppFilterApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
             );
and when i keep this at the bottom of reportapi route it works, but appfilterapi stops working.

Comment: Thank you, issue is fixed now by adding
[HttpGet]        [ActionName("list")]
in controller before method

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed now by adding

```
 [HttpGet] 
 [ActionName("list")]
```

in controller before method.